# $ b_n $ sequence of subsequential limits of $ a_n $ and $ b_n $ not bounded above $ \Rightarrow a_n $ not bounded

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Can you please verify my proof of the following statement:

Let $ \{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \, $ be a sequence in $ \mathbb{R} $ and let $ \{b_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \, $ be a set of subsequential limits of $ \{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \, $ (not necessarily all of them). If $ \{b_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \, $ is not bounded above, then neither is $ \{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty $.

Proof:

Assume $ \{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \,$ is bounded above and therefore $ \exists M \gt 0 \,$ such that $ a_n \in \left[-M, M\right], \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. For all $ L^{'} \gt M \,$ we will take the neighborhood $ \left(L^{'} - \frac{L^{'} + M}{2}, L^{'} + \frac{L^{'} + M}{2} \right) \,$, which has no elements of $ \{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \Rightarrow \not \exists L^{'} \gt M : L^{'} \, $ is a subsequential limit of $ \{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \,$ and therefore, $ M $ is an upper bound of $ \{b_n \mid n\in \mathbb{N}\} $ - contradiction.

Comment: Makes sense to me. But the mention of $-M$ is irrelevant, and not true.

Comment: Very nice. Stylistically speaking, I would consider expanding the $\implies$ in your proof just a little with a statement like "If a subsequence $a_{n_k}$ converged to $L'$, then it would eventually lie in $\left(L^{'} - \frac{L^{'} + M}{2}, L^{'} + \frac{L^{'} + M}{2} \right)$, hence...", just to make absolutely clear that you understand the relation between open sets like this and limits, but this is optional.

Comment: @311411 why isn't it true?

Comment: Inside your proof, we only know the $a_n$ are bounded above. Why should they be bounded below too?

Comment: @talopl Your proof works for sequences that are bounded, not just bounded above.